# How to store several lines in hashes of hash value

Tags: perl, hash

Hi I am new at perl and I stuck at one problem. I am creating hashes of hash in that I want to store several lines as value. I am getting only sing line in value.

File.txt

```
family (){
kapoor(){
member1(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}

member2(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}
}


rai(){
member1(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}

member2(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}
}
```

o/p should be:

```
family=>{

     kapoor => {
                member1=>{ 
                           0 to 5=> person : 2
                                    their name is bla & bla. 
                                    and bla bla......
                                    blaa.....

                          }   
               member2=> {
                          5 to 5 => person : 20
                                    their name is bla & bla bla. 
                                    and bla bla......
                                    blaa.....

                }

rai =>{
/...................etc
}
```

I am getting only single line in value, like

```
family=>{

     kapoor => {
                member1=>{ 
                           0 to 5=> person : 2
                                                                  }   
               member2=> {
                          5 to 5 => person : 20

                }

rai =>{
/...................etc
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
while(my$line=<$fh>)
  {

  if($line=~/$family_name_re/)
  {
      $family_name=$1;
  $family_count=$cell_count+1;
  }
  elsif ($line=~/$member_re/)
  {
  $member = $1;
 }
  elsif ($line=~/$age_re/)
 {
  $age_range=$1;

  $data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}=$line;
  }
}
  print Dumper(\%data);
  print "Number of cell is $cell_count\n";

 close ($fh);
```

I don't know how to assign multiple lines to value. I tried with while  at assigning value but didn't work.

Comment: in the last `elsif`, you can get the next lines (3 or whatever number of lines you need).. like `$line1 = <$fh>`, `$line2 = <$fh>`, etc and concatenate them with `$line` before assigning

Comment: Your input file is very confusing: the nesting doesn't look correct (member1 is two males) and you ignore the male grouping. Also your code is incomplete since you don't give us the regex you're working with. As @spasic said, you should somehow read more lines at some point because currently you are only reading/storing data from the file in a line per line basis. That's the core problem for now.

Comment: The file format and its parsing don't make much sense, as ebailes said.  Your hash assignment seems fine, though (except that it is not clear what `$line` is actually).  Show us the file in its exact format, and the regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want %data to be a HoHoHoHoH and you have just a HoHoHoH.
For example you want

```
$data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}= {5 to 5 => person : 20,
                                their name => bla & bla bla,
                                bla => bla bla,
                                ...
                                }
```

In order to make this work, you may want to clean your import code,
and especially fix the line

```
$data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}=$line;
```

which is just a HoHoHoH, that's why your output is only 
one line, and not the hash you seem to want.

So, by psuedo code s/b something like

```
$data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}=%lines;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

push @{$data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}} , $line;

:)